# Understanding Single Responsibility Principle with this real piece of code

Tags: design-patterns, language-agnostic, single-responsibility-principle

So when you try to educate yourself for Single Responsibility Principle, you will most likely encounter definitions like "**One method should do just one thing**." and "**One class should be just one reason to change**". And then there are always bunch of toy examples like

```
class Dog {
    String bark() {
         return "Woof";
    }
}
```

But I find it very hard to apply this principle in Enterprise Application Development.

We have an application where we have "Project Elements", "Activities" and "Employees". An Employee will have many Activities, and an Activity can have one Project Element.

Some Employees are assigned to all Project Elements, some are only assigned to a bunch only. A Project Element can be removed from an Employee and new ones can be assigned. Employee can only add new Activities with Project Elements assigned to her. If no Project Elements are assigned, this means all are available.

A client of us had a requirement, they wanted to see a List of favorite Project Elements when adding new Activities. It does not matter how an Employee favorites a Project Element, it is a different View..

The Favorite Project elements must be ordered by some interesting rules. 
It depends on the total calculated work of Activities where a Favorite Project Element exists, only last 60 days being considered. At least it is a concrete requirement..

So it was my duty to implement this, and here is the implementation I have:

```
public List<ProjectElement> getFavoriteProjectElementsSortedDescendingByTotalWorkHoursInLast60Days(Employee owner) {
    // All Favorite Project Elements of Owner
    final List<ProjectElement> favoriteProjectElementsOfOwner
            = (List<ProjectElement>) (List<?>) favoriteBusinessObjectHelper.getAllFavoriteObjectsForBusinessObjectType(BusinessObjectType.PROJECT_ELEMENT.toInt());

    // Activities by Favorite Project Elements
    final List<Activity> favoriteProjectElementActivitiesForLast60Days
            = activityFinder.findByInProjectElementsForLastGivenDates(owner, favoriteProjectElementsOfOwner, 60);

    // Create a Map with Favorite Project Element - Calculated Work
    final Map<ProjectElement, Long> projectElementTotalWorkMap = new HashMap<ProjectElement, Long>();
    for (Activity activity : favoriteProjectElementActivitiesForLast60Days) {
        final ProjectElement activityProjectElement = activity.getProjectElement();
        if (!projectElementTotalWorkMap.containsKey(activityProjectElement)) {
            projectElementTotalWorkMap.put(activityProjectElement, 0L);
        }
        final long calculatedWork = activity.getCalculatedWork();
        final long totalCalculatedWork = projectElementTotalWorkMap.get(activityProjectElement) + calculatedWork;
        projectElementTotalWorkMap.put(activityProjectElement, totalCalculatedWork);
    }

    // Sort the Map by value descending
    final Map<ProjectElement, Long> sortedProjectElementTotalWorkMap
            = InnboundSortTool.sortByValueDescending(projectElementTotalWorkMap);

    // We do not want to show owners Favorite Project Element in the sidebar, if the Project Element is not available
    // for Employee anymore.. See the comments at the end of the file.
    final Set<ProjectElement> allowedProjectElementsForOwner = owner.getExplicitlyAssignedOnlyActiveProjectElements();

    final ArrayList<ProjectElement> projectElementsSorted = new ArrayList<ProjectElement>();
    for (ProjectElement projectElement : sortedProjectElementTotalWorkMap.keySet()) {
        if (allowedProjectElementsForOwner.size() == 0) { // This means Employee does not have any restrictions, all Project Elements are available to him.
            projectElementsSorted.add(projectElement);
        } else { // If Employee has assigned Project Elements, we must check if the Favorite Project Element is assigned to him..
            if (allowedProjectElementsForOwner.contains(projectElement)) {
                projectElementsSorted.add(projectElement); // If yes, add it to list, if no simply continue the loop without adding.
            }
        }
        if (projectElementsSorted.size() == 20) {
            break; // 20 is an arbitrary value, we do not want to show too many Favorite Project Elements in the UI.. Limit by 20.
        }
    }

    return projectElementsSorted;
}
```

Whoa, that is one big method, but it gets the job done. But it does not do one thing, does it? But if every method only does one thing, who is going to do the whole thing?

Do I introduce a Helper class and delegate everything to the that class and start calling:

```
final Map<ProjectElement, Long> projectElementTotalWorkMap = helper.CreateprojectElementTotalWorkMap(); 

helper.removeUnassignedFavoriteProjectElementsFromEmployee();
```

etc? But then do I introduce a Helper to Helper itself? Where does it even end? When I start refactoring like this, I end up having extremely useless methods, which just call other methods, and this class will look like:

```
List<ProjectElement> favoritesList;
favoritesList = helper.doThis();
favoritesList = helper.doThat();
favoritesList = helper.sort();
return favoritesList;
```

Do I not understand this principle at all? I guess I do not, so here is the question, how should I fix this method so that it adheres to "SRP"?

Answer (score 1):

I think the important thing to keep in mind is to keep your responsibilities on the same level of abstraction. Meaning if you break this one function into several pieces, yes it will perform many things, however, it will have one responsibility - orchestrating work on a lower level of abstraction.

As an example here is the first part of your function after some refactor:

```
public List<ProjectElement> getFavoriteProjectElementsSortedDescendingByTotalWorkHoursInLast60Days(Employee owner) {
    // All Favorite Project Elements of Owner
    final List<ProjectElement> favoriteProjectElementsOfOwner
            = (List<ProjectElement>) (List<?>) favoriteBusinessObjectHelper.getAllFavoriteObjectsForBusinessObjectType(BusinessObjectType.PROJECT_ELEMENT.toInt());

    // Activities by Favorite Project Elements
    final List<Activity> favoriteProjectElementActivitiesForLast60Days
            = activityFinder.findByInProjectElementsForLastGivenDates(owner, favoriteProjectElementsOfOwner, 60);

    // Create a Map with Favorite Project Element - Calculated Work
    final Map<ProjectElement, Long> projectElementTotalWorkMap = this.makeFacoriteProjectMap(favoriteProjectElementActivitiesForLast60Days)
```

The functionality that generates your projectElementTotalWorkMap was moved to a private function. So now it is no longer your main functions responsibility to figure out how to build the map. If there is an error in the way that map is generated, you only need to to look in the function you moved it to:

```
private Map<ProjectElement, Long> projectElementTotalWorkMap makeFacoriteProjectMap(List<Activity> favoriteProjectElementActivitiesForLast60Days)
{
    Map<ProjectElement, Long> projectElementTotalWorkMap= new HashMap<ProjectElement, Long>();
    for (Activity activity : favoriteProjectElementActivitiesForLast60Days) {
        final ProjectElement activityProjectElement = activity.getProjectElement();
        if (!projectElementTotalWorkMap.containsKey(activityProjectElement)) {
            projectElementTotalWorkMap.put(activityProjectElement, 0L);
        }
        final long calculatedWork = activity.getCalculatedWork();
        final long totalCalculatedWork = projectElementTotalWorkMap.get(activityProjectElement) + calculatedWork;
        projectElementTotalWorkMap.put(activityProjectElement, totalCalculatedWork);
    }

    return projectElementTotalWorkMap;
}
```

Previously, if you discovered an error in the way you generate this map, you would have had to change the main function. The main function would also have to change if, for example, things happened in the wrong order.

Orchestration is now the main functions only responsibility.

This same refactor can be applied to generate your `projectElementsSorted` ArrayList, after which the function `getFavoriteProjectElementsSortedDescendingByTotalWorkHoursInLast60Days`would have 1 responsibility - orchestrating the steps to provide you with the sorted list of working hours in the last 60 days.

There will be other small private functions each with their own responsibility. Even with  this many private functions each doing it's own thing, the main class this code is in still has one responsibility to the outside world.

To tie in with your dog barking example I will make another analogy. Let's say you have a trainer to train your dog to perform a routine in the circus. At the end of the day the dog must be able to do this:

```
class Dog
{
    public void PerformRoutine()
    {
        this.bark();
        this.sit();
        this.walkInCircle();
        this.rollOver();
    }
    //...
}
```

Even though this function does many things, the only reason for this function to ever change would be if the routine changes. However, if the sound the dog makes when it barks needs to change, you will not look here. Everything in the `PerformRoutine` function is on the same level of abstraction.

In the context of enterprise applications you often have a service/api layer orchestrating the saving and loading and calling of domain objects. These functions appear to be violating SR but these are all part of the same responsibility still. The saving and loading is the responsibility of you repositories. The actual logic is the responsibility of your domain objects. These APIs/services are in fact just doing 1 thing - orchestrating and delegating to other services.

I hope this can help you.

**EDIT:** To answer your question on what the value of all of this is:

Consider the  previous dog example without SR:

```
class Dog
{
    public IEnumerator PerformRoutine()
    {
        this.audioController.PlaySound("c:/bar.mp3");
        this.animationControl.Play("Sit.anim");

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);

        this.animationController.Play("stand.anim");         

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);

        foreach(Vector3 pos in this.WalkPositions)
        {
            this.animationController.Play("walk.anim");
            this.position.lerpTo(pos, 5.0f); // move to position over 5 seconds.

        }

        this.animationController.Play("roll.anim");
    }
    //...
}
```

Any new team member must now understand exactly the  implementation details of this function in order to understand what it really does. This is already heavily simplified.

If you ask a new team member (or even if you revisit your old code) you would ideally want to glance over it and understand what it does. The function name "PerformRoutine" does not prepare the reader for animation or movement logic.

If you are sent back to this code because the dog walks in a square instead of a circle it is harder work to adjust this code.

Now apply this same reasoning in an enterprise solution with hundreds of thousands of lines of code and thousands of functions. It becomes so unmanageable that eventually you want to quit.

Here is another example from a REAL LIFE integration I've done for an investment firm. Here is roughly the 3rd party code that took a few days off of my development schedule:

```
public List<Event> getEventData()
{
    var toReturn = new List<Event>(this.eventData);
    this.eventData.Clear();
    return toReturn;
}
```

Behold. Calling this function twice in a row gives drastically different outputs because the writer did not bother with either SR or proper naming.

With minimal effort this could have been 2 functions - `getEventDate()` and `clearEventData()`. I would have even settled for 1 function with a different name - `getAndClearEventData()` although the latter violates SR.

Comment: Yes, definitely helpful, thank you. But still, just moving 5 lines of code to a private method? Probably I am the one who is unable to understand the concept (or the advantage) that comes with it..

Comment: @KorayTugay You are right that it seems pointless and like extra work sometimes. However the power of this for me comes when I get new members on my team that need to understand the code. If they need to understand the big picture they will just be able to look at these "orchestration" functions. Only when stuff goes wrong will they need to go deeper, and then hopefully they will be able to figure out where to look. It is also very intimidating and cognitive overload to look at a big function. A good read would be Clean Code by Robert Martin.